# Convert X,Y to angle

Tags: java, android, angle

I need a way to convert X and Y coordinates to an angle. I have this code but I need this layout:

```
 180
```

`90  270`

`360`

```
private double getAngle(double xTouch, double yTouch) {
    double x = xTouch - (slideBtn.getWidth() / 2d);
    double y = slideBtn.getHeight() - yTouch - (slideBtn.getHeight() / 2d);
    switch (getQuadrant(x, y)) {
        case 1:
            return Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        case 2:
            return 180 - Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        case 3:
            return 180 + (-1 * Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI);
        case 4:
            return 360 + Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

/**
 * @return The selected quadrant.
 */
private static int getQuadrant(double x, double y) {
    if (x >= 0) {
        return y >= 0 ? 1 : 4;
    } else {
        return y >= 0 ? 2 : 3;
    }
}
```

Edit, to clarify the problem: The problem I had was that I was getting the wrong angles for the x,y angles. For instance: 0/360 degrees is the top side of the circle and 180 degrees is the bottom side of the circle. I tried to fix it using the code above (with different quadrants, but that didn't work). The accepted answer did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure what are you trying to achieve, but isn't it easier to just use the atan2 function to get an angle?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double, double)

If you are not familiar with the function you can read here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Edit, code example:

So, here is some code I think that is useful, after the discussion

```
public static double getAngle(int x, int y)
{
    return 1.5 * Math.PI - Math.atan2(y,x); //note the atan2 call, the order of paramers is y then x
}
```

Basically, it calculates an angle between the negative Y-axis with the positive clockwise direction. I hope that is what you have been looking for.

Comment: When I do the method getAngle() I get the wrong angle layout. So I need the angle layout as specified above. The atan2 does not the thing I wanted... 180 degrees instead of 90 degrees on top. So rotate the whole angle 90 degrees, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: When you get the results of atan2 you should than just add PI/2 to rotate the angle counterclockwise for 90 degrees, if that is what is your problem. But the problem is I don't get it where is 0 degrees on your layout and are angles increasing clockwise or counterclockwise?

Comment: 0 degrees is at the same point as 360 degrees but I will try the atan2! Thanks and I will accept your answer when it worked

Comment: I'm slow sometimes... In that case I think you should subtract the angle you get from atan2 from -90 degrees. That way you reverse the orientation and the coordinate start.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope that is what you have been looking for

Comment: I will try that today! (Netherlands ;) ) I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var x,x1,x2,y,y1,y2;
  var cells = 'cell0';
  var h,w;
  var cx,cy;
  var dx,dy;
  var derajat;
  var deg;
  var ang;
  var light;
  var control;
   function mouse_watch(event){
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;
    cell_data(cells);
    koordinat(x2,y2);
    busur(derajat);
   }
   function koordinat(x2,y2){
    x2 = x-cx;
    y2 = y-cy;
    yk = y2;
    xk = x2;
   }
   function busur(derajat){

    y1 = Math.sqrt((Math.abs(yk)*Math.abs(yk))+(Math.abs(xk)*(Math.abs(xk))));
    x1 = 0;
    dy = yk-y1;
    dx = xk-x1;
    rad = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    derajat = rad * (360 / Math.PI);
    cell = document.getElementById(cells);
    ang = cell.getElementsByClassName('angle0')[0];
    ang.style.transform = 'rotate('+derajat+'deg)';
    light = ang.getElementsByClassName('points')[0];
    light.style.height = y1+'px';
   }
   function cell_data(cells){
    cell = document.getElementById(cells);
    h = Number(cell.style.height.replace('px',''));
    w = Number(cell.style.width.replace('px',''));
    cy = Number(cell.style.top.replace('px',''))+h/2;
    cx = Number(cell.style.left.replace('px',''))+w/2;
   }
```

```css
.preview_engine{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #2E8AE6;
    color: white;
   }
   body{
    cursor: default;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
   }
   .fieldwork{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
   }
   .cell{
    position: relative;
    transition : width 2s, height 2s, top 2s, left 2s;
    background-color: red;
   }
   .angle0{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -75px;
    left: -75px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition : width 2s, height 2s, top 2s, left 2s;
   }
   .points{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 95px;
    top: 95px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 1em;
    opacity: none;
   }
```

```html
  <div class="fieldwork" onmousemove="mouse_watch(event)">
   <div class='cell' id="cell0" style="width:50px;height:50px;top:200px;left:400px;">
    <div class="angle0">
     <div class="points"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I asked for a java answer not a javascript answer ;) But I might be able to rewrite it for java, so thanks though!

Comment: can you help me to write my game in java ?? 
i have made a game in javascript that run in browser, 
but i stuck in gpu memory that use to run the game, if the game create more object it make the flash run slow.

Answer (score 0):

This class converts the input of a joystick to an angle, 0 being the positive y axis being 0 degrees, positive x being 90, negative y as 180, and negative x as 270

```
public class GetAngle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(getAngle(-1,0));

    }

    public static double getAngle(double x, double y) {

        // Checking if the joystick is at center (0,0) and returns a 'stand still'
        // command by setting the return to 99999
        if (x == 0 && y == 0) {

            return (99999);

            // Returns a value based on the quadrant and does some math to deliver the angle
            // of the coordinates
        } else if (x >= 0 && y > 0) {

            return (90 - (Math.atan(y / x) * 180 / Math.PI));

        } else if (x > 0 && y <= 0) {

            return (90 - (Math.atan(y / x) * 180 / Math.PI));

        } else if (x <= 0 && y < 0) {

            return (180 + (Math.atan(y / x) * 180 / Math.PI));

        } else if (x < 0 && y >= 0) {

            return (270 - (Math.atan(y / x) * 180 / Math.PI));

        } else
            return (99999);

    }

}
```